# VHDL equivalent to Verilog "10'h234"

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I just need to know how to translate constant values from Verilog to VHDL. I wonder if I could still indicate the range and if it is hex, oct, binary, etc., just like in Verilog:
14'h1 -> I do not want to type anything like X"00000000000001"
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer depends on what VHDL standard you use.

Before VHDL 2008, hex constants could only be directly expressed when the number of binary digits was a multiple of 4 (the length of an hex nibble).

`x"0001"` is a 16-bit constant.

With VHDL 2008, you can specify the bit length of the constant:

`x"0001"` is still a 16-bit constant, whereas `14x"0001"` is what you want: a 14 bit constant.

If you are working with an earlier standard, you must work around this limitation like this:

`std_logic_vector(resize("1", 14))` or `(0 => '1', others => '0')`

Answer (score 0):

```
constant my_const : std_logic_vector(13 downto 0) := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(1, 14));
```

or

```
constant my_const : std_logic_vector(13 downto 0) := "00" & x"001";
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!